# .htaccess redirect multiple urls to their corresponding new pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, path

I'd like to redirect the following urls with .htaccess:

/books/garden **to** /garden-books 
/movies/dvd-comedy **to** /dvd/comedy 
/music-soundtracks/new **to** /music/soundtracks

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an even simpler solution you can also try this:

```
Redirect 301 /books/garden /garden-books
Redirect 301 /movies/dvd-comedy /dvd/comedy
Redirect 301 /music-soundtracks/new /music/soundtracks
```

The old url is first after "Redirect 301", then the new url.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your .htaccess file in your site's root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(books)/(garden)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2-%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(garden)-(books)/?$ /$2/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+movies/(dvd)-(comedy)/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(dvd)/(comedy)/?$ /movies/$1-$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(music)-(soundtracks)/new/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(music)/(soundtracks)/?$ /$1-$2/new [NC,L]
```

---

Yes, it's possible but you need to consider this: if your actual URL is, say, `/page.php?var=val`, and your pretty URL is `/page/var/val`, then the above rules make sure that not only the pretty version `/page/var/val` works, but if someone tries to access that actual `/page.php?var=val` they are redirected back to `/page/var/val` as well.

So, if you're only interested in resolving the pretty URLs, you can use only the following.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(garden)-(books)/?$ /$2/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(dvd)/(comedy)/?$ /movies/$1-$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(music)/(soundtracks)/?$ /$1-$2/new [NC,L]
```