# htaccess multiple conditions same URL redirects

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Require multiple URLs with different segments (and / or query parameters) to redirect to a single landing URL and terminate

e.g.

```
/abc/def?hij=klm  => / (ROOT of domain)
/xzy?=(*)         => / (ROOT of domain  - anything )
```

I would like to something like below (IF QueryString contains ... or contains .... etc)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^abc/def(*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^xyz?(*)
: (any other conditions here)
RewriteRule /$ http://www.example.com [301, L]
```

I know it can be done on a per line basis as per [.htaccess redirect multiple urls to their corresponding new pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484170/htaccess-redirect-multiple-urls-to-their-corresponding-new-pages)
but I probably have several hundred to enter which all go to the root domain. Hence the attempt to catch multiple conditions and rewrite them all to the root domain.

So what I'm trying to avoid is a single line for each redirect. that is the fallback if the above is not possible.
Any assistance is appreciated.

Trying to understand this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html
but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: The rewriting module offers a simple`[OR]` combination for rewriting conditions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with the attempt you posted. This does not really read like you actually considered the good examples given in the documentation you referenced...

Here is a version that should get you started, though you obviously need to adapt it to your specific requirements:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)abc=def(?:&|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)xyz=([^&]*)(?:&|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)uvw=([^&]*)(?:&|$) [OR]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried a few combinations but cannot seem to get the result I want. I've gone with RewriteRule ... ..... [R=301,L,QSD]. This with combinations of (.*) and (abc|def) produced a usable result. Thanks again for the detailed response and recommendations for using the config file instead of htaccess. Hopefully I can get this running and confirm for others. 302 is much better for testing.